# woocommerce grouped products display changes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been searching for days on codecanyon, wordpress etc'  for a plug that will allow me to change the default display of grouped products (currently) `QTY | Title | Price and add to cart at the bottom` to:

```
---Header ----
Thumbnail | SKU | Title |Price | QTY and add to cart near each
```

Does anyone know of such plug or the code for this?

Comment: Grouped products are supposed to be an easy way to add multiple products to the cart at once (hence the one buttons at the bottom).

Comment: it's easy to add them on, but I'm looking for to add thumbnail, SKU and preposition them.